# Image insertion adding additional label which is not wanted

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert an image into a TeXShop document, however, as well as the image, a label with part of the image name is also being inserted. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can remove it? For example, if I am trying to insert an image called 'example flow diagram.png', I use the following code,

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example flow diagram.png}

\caption{example flow diagram}

\end{center}

\end{figure}
```

Not only does this insert the image into my document but it is off centre with the words 'flow diagram.png' written next to it.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Put an extra pair of braces around `example flow diagram` like `{{example flow diagram}.png}`. BTW you don't need `.png` there. As an alternative use `\udepackage{grffile}`

Comment: `"example flow diagram"` should probably work but really spaces in filenames should be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in the file name of the image are the problem. The following should work, assuming you rename the image accordingly. Furthermore, you should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in images to avoid additional white-space:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example_flow_diagram.png}
\caption{example flow diagram}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in your filename are a problem for LaTeX.
You can add the `grffile` package, which should fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}
[...]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example flow diagram.png}
\caption{example flow diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```